# Can we update records of custom metadata type in Visualforce page

Tags: custom-metadata

I am working with custom meta data type. Now I need to update record of custom  metadata type by edit button in vf page. Please tell me if we can update record of custom metadata in vf page.

Comment: Just so you know, using multiple .. at the end of your sentences is often perceived as rude. Also no need for thanks in your post, we're happy to help! I tidied up for you.

Answer (score 2):

As of the Spring '17 release, you can enqueue a metadata deployment of custom metadata records from Apex without a callout using the Apex Metadata API. See the [Metadata namespace documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_Metadata.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in the apex/visualforce [Custom Metadata Loader](https://github.com/forcedotcom/CustomMetadataLoader) by Salesforce. It's open source on GitHub and, as Mohith mentioned, has to make use of the Metadata API behind the scenes.

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342704/how-can-apex-update-custom-metadata-types-records-literals-values